# Bash script conditional to check if something was printed to terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I wrote a bash script to check if the correct password was entered when mounting a cifs share and report that to the user.

It doesn't work at all. I mean the whole part with `grep`, doesn't even make sense now that I look at it. It's doing grep on the original command, not the output after entering the password.

```
#!/bin/bash

share=sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.10/windows-share Shared/ -o user=me

$share

if [[ ($share | $(grep) "mount error (13): Permission denied") ]]; then
   echo "Wrong password"
else
    echo "Successful mount"
fi
```

This is what the output looks like if the password is wrong

```
Password for me@192.168.0.10/windows-share:
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

I am trying to grep that second line for my conditional statement. If that is even possible...

Comment: What do you intend the variable share to contain? The output of the sudo mount command? Or the command string itself?

Comment: The command itself. When I read the conditional:

- If this command that has run, contains this error, then report the error, else report a successful mount.

Comment: Why not simply test the numerical exit status of the mount command itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I am a complete noob when it comes to bash. This script is how I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your script:

1. If you want a variable to contain spaces (or other characters with special meaning to the shell, such as `;` or `&`) then you need to quote the entire string.  e.g.

   ```
    share='sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.10/windows-share Shared/ -o user=me'
   ```

   The way you wrote it, without quotes, you're setting `share=sudo` and then running `mount.cifs ...`, which is not at all what you want.
2. More importantly, the entire design of your script is wrong.  There's no need to define the $share variable and then execute it, and even if you do that, you won't get the result of the mount by grepping the variable (and that's ignoring the fact that your `($share | $(grep) ...)` line isn't even valid shell syntax).

Your script should be something more like this, which tests the exit code of the `sudo mount` command directly:

```
if sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.10/windows-share Shared/ -o user=me ; then
  echo Successful mount
else
  echo Mount failed
fi
```

BTW, see `man mount` and search for `EXIT STATUS` to see the full list of exit status codes which can be returned by `mount`.  Most of the time, though, you only really need to care about success (0) or failure (anything else).

If you did need to handle some or all of the non-zero exit codes, you'd do it more like this:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.10/windows-share Shared/ -o user=me
result=$?

case "$result" in
  0) echo Successful mount ;;
  1) echo incorrect invocation or permissions ;;
  2) echo 'system error (out of memory, cannot fork, no more loop devices)' ;;
  4) echo internal mount bug ;;
  8) echo user interrupt ;;
 16) echo problems writing or locking /etc/mtab ;;
 32) echo mount failure ;;
 64) echo some mount succeeded ;; 
esac
```

Comment: 1. Thank you for your response. I actually did have quotes in my script's string but forgot to paste them here.

2. I didn't think it was valid syntax, but I thought maybe I was on the right path by using grep.

I don't really understand your script. It does work, so thank you, but I am trying to understand.

- First, where are the square [[ ]] brackets for the conditional?
- I read the condtional as "If I run this command, it succeeds" Where does it even check else?
- How is checking the EXIT STATUS with just a simple conditional?

Comment: The square brackets aren't required for `if`, they're used if you want to perform tests on variables or filenames.  Every program returns an exit code when run, which can be either 0 (true, success, normal, no problem) or non-zero (false, failure, error).  This can be tested directly with `if` (e.g there's a program called `true` which always returns true - you can use it in an if statement like `if true; then do ... ; fi`.  and you can use any other program or pipeline of commands in place of `true`).

Comment: BTW, `[` is a program (see `/usr/bin/[`), a synonym for `test` (e.g. `/usr/bin/test`).  Originally, they were only standalone programs but they're used so often in scripts that they're now also built-in to shells for performance.  `[[` is different, it was never a stand-alone program, it was written to be an enhanced version of `[` that can do things that `[` can't. It still returns true or false (0 or non-zero).

Comment: And, finally, the exit code from the last program (or shell built-in command) executed is captured in shell variable `$?`. This lasts only until another program/command is executed (and then $? is the exit code from THAT program/command), but you can copy it to another variable (e.g. as in my script above: `result=$?`) if you need it for longer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand your example now, though I really should find a Bash course so I can learn more. I marked your response as the accepted answer.